# NSImage from NSData information

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've got an `NSData` object that supposedly contains image data in the TIFF format. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VjyuG/) is an example of the output (in the top-left box).

However, when I `NSLog` it out, I get the following:

```
<NSImage 0x10013f620 Size={200, 200} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x1001220d0 Size={200, 200} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=200x200 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x100150070"
)>
```

Which makes me thing it might actually be a BitmapImage.

Anyways, when I do the following:

```
NSData *artworkData;
NSImage *image;
artworkData = [self.currentTrack artwork]; // actually sets memory, like expected
image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:artworkData]; // causes the error
```

I get this error:

```
2012-12-03 02:39:56.263 test[92556:303] -[NSImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10064ec90
2012-12-03 02:39:56.264 test[92556:303] -[NSImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10064ec90
```

Any ideas? This has been bothering me for quite a while now.

Thank you!

Comment: What is artworkData? Did you mean data? And what does .SOMETHING do? You should give a bit more detail here and you should not change your code for stackoverflow. That just adds the risk of additional errors and may mislead those who try helping.

Comment: @HermannKlecker adjusted, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing with an `NSData` object? The thing you `NSLog`ged is no data, it's already an `NSImage`. Maybe you could specify what exactly it is you logged?

Comment: @waldrumpus that was it. the documentation i was going off of said it was NSData; turns out it was an NSImage. Thank you! Feel free to add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are dealing with an `NSData` object? The object in your log output is no data, it's already an NSImage. Therefore, trying to use it as an argument for `-[NSImage initWithData:]` will fail.